# Can bash expand a quoted and/or escaped string variable into words?

Tags: bash, shell, string, eval, bash-expansion

I have a `bash` shell variable containing a string formed of multiple *words* delimited by whitespace. The string can contain escapes, such as escaped whitespace within a word. Words containing whitespace may alternatively be quoted.

A shell variable that is used unquoted (`$FOO` instead of `"$FOO"`) becomes multiple words but quotes and escapes in the original string have no effect.

**How can a string be split into words, giving consideration to quoted and escaped characters?**

#### Background

A server offers restricted access over `ssh` using the `ForceCommand` option in the `sshd_config` file to force execution of a script regardless of the command-line given to the `ssh` client.

The script uses the variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` (which is a string, set by `ssh`, that contains the command-line provided to the `ssh` client) to set its argument list before proceeding. So, a user doing

```
$ ssh some_server foo 'bar car' baz
```

will see the script execute and it will have `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` set to `foo bar car baz` which would become four arguments when the script does

```
set -- ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}
```

Not the desired result. So the user tries again:

```
$ ssh some_server foo bar\ car baz
```

Same result - the backslash in the second argument needs to be escaped for the client's shell so `ssh` sees it. What about these:

```
$ ssh some_server foo 'bar\ car' baz
$ ssh some_server foo bar\\ car baz
```

Both work, as would a [`printf "%q"` quoting wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593480) that can simplify the client-side quoting.

Client-side quoting allows `ssh` to send the correctly quoted string to the server so that it receives `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` with the backslash intact: `foo bar\ car baz`.

However there is still a problem because `set` does not consider the quoting or escaping. There is a solution:

```
eval set -- ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}
```

but it is unacceptable. Consider

```
$ ssh some_server \; /bin/sh -i
```

Very undesirable: `eval` can't be used because the input can't be controlled.

**What is required is the string expansion capability of `eval` without the execution part.**

Comment: I thought I might indirect through an array and use `declare` instead of `eval`. But that's just as evil. And so is `local`.

Comment: I could not find this in the manual, but `declare -a m="(${s})"` appears to expand quotes yet does not allow injecting a command by using a semicolon `;` or a closing brace `)`.  It does throw a runtime syntax error that cannot be caught.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `read`:

```
read -a ssh_args <<< "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}"
set -- "${ssh_args[@]}"
```

This will parse words from `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` into the array `ssh_args`, treating backslash (`\`) as an escape character. The array elements are then given as arguments to `set`. It works with an argument list passed through `ssh` like this:

```
$ ssh some_server foo 'bar\ car' baz
$ ssh some_server foo bar\\ car baz
```

A [printf "%q" quoting ssh wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593480) allows these:

```
$ sshwrap some_server foo bar\ car baz
$ sshwrap some_server foo 'bar car' baz
```

Here is such a wrapper example:

```
#!/bin/bash
h=$1; shift
QUOTE_ARGS=''
for ARG in "$@"
do
  ARG=$(printf "%q" "$ARG")
  QUOTE_ARGS="${QUOTE_ARGS} $ARG"
done
ssh "$h" "${QUOTE_ARGS}"
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to quote an string:

See `${parameter@operator}` section in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

- For a single var:

```
"${var@Q}"
```

`a` -> `'a'`,  `a'b` -> `'a'\''b'`.

- For an array,

```
"@{array[@]@Q}"
```

will quote each element in the array then join with space into a big string.

- For program arguments `$@`

```
"${@@Q}"
```

(probably require Bash 4.4+, if not available you can use printf "%q" ... but you lose the ability of quoting each elements in array)

### How to de-quote the quoted string back into array

I only found 1 safe way is as @eel ghEEz pointed:

```
declare -a array="($QUOTED_ARGS)"
```

EDIT 2022/08/31: it is important to pass quoted args to avoid command injection.

More precisely, it should be

```
JOINED_ARGMENTS_STRING="......"
declare -a array="(${JOINED_ARGMENTS_STRING@Q})"
```

Sample:

```
cat <<'EOF' > show_args
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo "ARG_$((++i))=$arg"
done
EOF
chmod +x show_args
```

```
cat <<'EOF' > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
QUOTED_ARGS=${@@Q}    # this is important!!!!!!
echo QUOTED_ARGS is "$QUOTED_ARGS"

echo de-quote QUOTED_ARGS
declare -a args="($QUOTED_ARGS)"
./show_args "${args[@]}"
EOF
chmod +x test.sh
```

### Tests:

```
ARGS=("a a a" "b'b'b" 'c"c"c')
./show_args "${ARGS[@]}"
```

you can show it is an array with 3 elements

```
ARG_1=a a a
ARG_2=b'b'b
ARG_3=c"c"c
```

Let us see how the quotes and de-quotes work

```
./test.sh "${ARGS[@]}"
```

or

```
./test.sh "a a a" "b'b'b" 'c"c"c'
```

The result is

```
QUOTED_ARGS is 'a a a' 'b'\''b'\''b' 'c"c"c'
de-quote QUOTED_ARGS
ARG_1=a a a
ARG_2=b'b'b
ARG_3=c"c"c
```

EDIT 2022/08/31: added a test of injection attempts:

```
./test.sh "\$(echo test >&2)"
```

Result:

```
QUOTED_ARGS is '$(echo test >&2)'
de-quote QUOTED_ARGS
ARG_1=$(echo test >&2)
```

The "echo test" command did not get called, that is fine.

Successfully restored.

Comment: This still seems to be implemented unsafely by Bash, similarly to `eval`. `inc="\$(echo test >&2)"`, then `declare -a x="("${inc}"/*)"` outputs `test` immediately (to stderr).

Comment: @eelghEEz thanks for pointing out this, that is really dangerous.

Comment: @eelghEEz, strangely, I found that `./test.sh "\$(echo test >&2)"` runs well, no injection happened, wondering why.

Comment: Got the reason, it is because I ran `QUOTED_ARGS=${@@Q}` first, so avoided the injection.

Comment: @eelghEEz I have tested the injection attempts, it is fine now, no worry.

Comment: Thanks, your clarification makes me understand that the risk is supplying a malicious input not to the quote-then-dequote pipeline but to dequoting alone.  The latter chance is probably lower.  (In addition to command expansion, the `declare -a name="(ARGS_TEXT)"` trick terminates the bash instance on seeing syntax errors in ARGS_TEXT such as unpaired quotes.